# How do i configure Stream Mode in Drools

Tags: spring-boot, drools

Can't seem to get the config right to enable Drools to run in Stream mode
Am getting 
The requested KieBase "defaultKieBase" has been set to run in CLOUD mode but requires features only available in STREAM mode

kieContainer code needs something to apply the 
   KieBaseConfiguration config
to the 
   KieBuilder kieBuilder

Any ideas how to achieve this -- or please correct the code below

```
@Bean
KieContainer kieContainer() {
    logger.info("Creating kieContainer with '" + rulesFile + "'");
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

    KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    kieFileSystem.write(kieServices.getResources().newClassPathResource(rulesFile));


    KieBaseConfiguration config = kieServices.newKieBaseConfiguration();
    config.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);        

    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
    kieBuilder.buildAll();
    KieModule kieModule = kieBuilder.getKieModule();

    return kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
}
```

Comment: `The requested KieBase "defaultKieBase" has been set to run in CLOUD mode` --> can you show where this is done?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work

```
@Bean
KieContainer kieContainer() {
    logger.info("Creating kieContainer with '" + rulesFile + "'");
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    kieFileSystem.write(kieServices.getResources().newClassPathResource(rulesFile));
    KieModuleModel kieModuleModel = kieServices.newKieModuleModel();
    KieBaseModel baseModel = kieModuleModel.newKieBaseModel("defaultKBase")
            .setDefault(true)
            .setEventProcessingMode(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);
    baseModel.newKieSessionModel("defaultKSession")
             .setDefault(true);
    kieFileSystem.writeKModuleXML(kieModuleModel.toXML());        
    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
    kieBuilder.buildAll();

    KieModule kieModule = kieBuilder.getKieModule();
    return kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
}
```